# Register new pageasynctask with async Task method that takes parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, async-await

I have this method in an asp.net webforms project:

```
private async Task SomeMethod(int accID){ // }
```

I want to do this in the page_load, but I'm not sure how to handle the parameters.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RegisterAsyncTask(new PageAsyncTask(SomeMethod(int accID)));

       // etc
}
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RegisterAsyncTask(new PageAsyncTask(() => SomeMethod(accID: 1000)));

       // etc
}
```

Comment: Thanks Noseratio. This works, but would it be possible to not specify a 'default' value of 1000 for accID?

Comment: @AJ, do you mean `new PageAsyncTask(() => SomeMethod())`? That's possible.

Comment: I get an error message "No overload for method 'SomeMethod' takes 0 takes arguments". Not to worry, what I've done is add a condition for 0 in my method.

Comment: @AJ, right, then it means what it means: there's no version of `SomeMethod` which would provide default value for `accID`.

Comment: @AJ private async Task SomeMethod(int accID = 1000){ // }

Comment: how do I store data in a variable which is returned from `() => SomeMethod(accID: 1000)` this method?

Answer (score 1):

First, I know am too late to answer this, but this may still help others struggling like me.

So, you could make all the parameters of the async method optional like below:

```
private async Task SomeMethod(int accID=0){ // }
```

and then register the task in the page load event like below:

```
RegisterAsyncTask(new PageAsyncTask(() => SomeMethod()));
```

This works fine for me.

Comment: I want to downvote this because it doesn't really answer his question like noseratio's does