# Overload resolution failed for New PageAsyncTask

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asynchronous, webforms, .net-4.5

I am trying to do some asynchronous operations in ASP.NET 4.5 Web Forms. I received this error when following several online tutorials:

> Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'New' can be called
>   with these arguments:
>
> 'Public Sub New(handler As System.Func(Of System.Threading.CancellationToken, System.Threading.Tasks.Task))':
>   Value of type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task' cannot be converted to
>   'System.Func(Of System.Threading.CancellationToken,
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task)'.
>
> 'Public Sub New(handler As System.Func(Of System.Threading.Tasks.Task))': Value of type
>   'System.Threading.Tasks.Task' cannot be converted to 'System.Func(Of System.Threading.Tasks.Task)'.

Here is the code (similar to [this tutorial](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/working-with-asynchronous-operations-in-asp.net-4.5-web-forms.htm)):

```
Imports System.Threading.Tasks

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
     RegisterAsyncTask(New PageAsyncTask(DoStuffAsync))
     ' etc...
End Sub

Private Async Function DoStuffAsync() As Task
    Await SomeTask()
End Function
```

It's the only error in the solution. As far as I can tell, this is exactly what is in the tutorials (translated from C#). I did notice in the MSDN documentation that the `PageAsyncTask` uses several additional parameters for event handlers (which require additional code), but all the tutorials I've read online eschew these and only put the function name (`Func(Of Task)`). What am I missing?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22655333/register-new-pageasynctask-with-async-task-method-that-takes-parameters) is an example where the person uses only the method name (and passes the method's parameter).

Comment: Try using `RegisterAsyncTask(New PageAsyncTask(AddressOf DoStuffAsync))`.

Comment: Thanks @Mark. This works. If you make it an answer I can accept it. I guess that in C# the conversion is implicit(?) C# doesn't need an equivalent of `AddressOf` in these cases. Reviewing documentation on delegates provided some additional information once I knew where to look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C#, you can just use the method name to pass a function delegate as a parameter.  In VB.NET, you need to use the `AddressOf` operator to pass a delegate.  e.g.

```vb
RegisterAsyncTask(New PageAsyncTask(AddressOf DoStuffAsync))
```